# An ad for Stack Overflow *on* Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, advertising, design

Just noticed (again) an ad *for* SO *on* SO.

Seems the ad-scheduling should/could be a *teensy* bit more intelligent.  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I don't really think there are any ads for SO on SO. There may be ads for SO Careers, other StackExchange sites, etc, but I have never seen an actual ad for SO.

There is one that says: "Want to reach top devs? There's a site for that.", but that is one for advertising on SO.

---

About the timing issue. I would expect to see the SO-related ads more often that any other, especially if publishers put limits on where their ads are shown, how many people, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Even if there *was* an ad for Stack Overflow (which I haven't seen), what's wrong with that? It would be an intelligent bit of self-promotion. Only a small percentage of people reaching the site know about all its advantages. Stickiness.

Haven't you ever seen an ad for the television station you are watching? A "subscription pitch" for the magazine you are browsing? Wal-mart is *full* of advertisements about their lower prices. These cookies I just opened have a card in it about how fresh they are. So...

Comment: That just doesn't make sense ... How about we start ads for ads ?

Comment: @Idigas: there already are http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34181/stack-overflow-ad-gallery/36267#36267

Comment: When you have unused ad space, these ads cost you nothing. It could just be an empty space. Or maybe a little thing that says "Nobody wants to advertise on our site"

Comment: @voyager - so ? ... i don't base my opinion on whether it's been done or asked before.

Comment: @Jon B - true. ads i see on tv also cost me nothing; but because of the amount of some, i stopped watching some channels. and as little as it may be, now it's costing them.